# Bind User Input from TextBoxes to a Collection of Objects and Populate via ComboBox in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I am fairly new to WPF and MVVM but so far I couldn't find a way for this two way binding scenario. I should also mention that this NOT a school project but my own interest in learning different aspects of MVVM for my own good.

My View contains a Window with TextBoxes that collect user input (SchoolName, SchoolAddress, SchoolTelephone etc). The View also has an Add button that should save input from TextBoxes, create a School object and then populate a ComboBox (with school names). So every time user clicks Add button a new school appears in the ComboBox list and all TextBoxes are reset and ready for new school input. Another condition I wish to preserve is that you can have a two way binding of TextBoxes with a selected item from the ComboBox. So when you select a school from the list, TextBoxes are populated with its object's info and it can be further edited.

What I've managed to get is I've bound my TextBoxes to properties, I have bound my ComboBox ItemsSource with the ObservableCollection of Schools, the SelectedItem was bound to the SelectedSchool property and I've bound my Add Button to the AddSchoolCommand, so the collection does get populated.

What I cannot accomplish is find a way to bind SelectedSchool property such that I could modify existing School objects through the ComboBox items list as well as somehow start with cleared TextBoxes every time I Add a new school. The TextBoxes serve as both input collectors and display of the existing School data.

So here is my approach:

```
// ViewModelBase

    internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

// ViewModel:

 public ObservableCollection<School> Schools { get; set; }
 public RelayCommand AddSchoolCommand { get; set; }

 string _SchoolName;
     public string SchoolName
            {
                get
                {
                    return _SchoolName;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (_SchoolName != value)
                    {
                        _SchoolName = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged("SchoolName");
                    }
                }
            }

    string _SchoolAddress;
     public string SchoolAddress
            {
                get
                {
                    return _SchoolName;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (_SchoolAddress != value)
                    {
                        _SchoolAddress = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged("SchoolAddress");
                    }
                }
            }

    string _SchooTelephone;
     public string SchooTelephone
            {
                get
                {
                    return _SchooTelephone;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (_SchooTelephone != value)
                    {
                        _SchoolAddress = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged("SchooTelephone");
                    }
                }
            }

    object _SelectedSchool;
    public object SelectedSchool
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedSchool;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedSchool != value)
            {
                _SelectedSchool = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedSchool");
            }
        }
    }

    public ViewModelResume()
    {
       Schools = new ObservableCollection<School>();
       AddSchoolCommand = new RelayCommand(AddSchool);
    }

    void AddSchool(Object obj)
    {
        Schools.Add(new School
        {
            Name = SchoolName,
            Address = SchoolAddress,
            Telephone = SchoolTelephone,
        });
    }

// XAML

<Grid Width="358" Height="135">
<TextBox x:Name="schoolName" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="School Name" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="10,9,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="166" Text="{Binding SchoolName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="schoolAddress" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="School Address" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" Height="26" Margin="0,9,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="167" Text="{Binding School Address, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="schoolTelephone" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="School Telephone" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="10,79,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133" Text="{Binding SchoolTelephone, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="schoolsList" Text="Schools List" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,155,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="268" ToolTip="List of attended schools" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Schools}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSchool}" DisplayMemberPath="SchoolName" />
<Button x:Name="saveSchoolButton" Content="Add" Margin="318,155,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Command="{Binding AddSchoolCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text boxes are listening to properties in view model which are unaware of selectedSchool.
you can bind your text boxes to selectedSchool.Properties

first make your SelectedSchool of Type School and initiate it like this

```
School _SelectedSchool = new School();
```

and then change all text boxes to bind to selected school properties

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedSchool.SchoolName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

and then when you add

```
void AddSchool(Object obj)
{
    Schools.Add(SelectedSchool);
    SelectedSchool = New School();

}
```

Comment: What happens with your approach is when I click add, the TextBoxes remain filled with data and if I want to add a new record, I have to modify whatever is already is in the TextBox (it doesn't get an empty object), which means I end up changing my School Object #1.

Comment: well if you do SelectedSchool = New School();

it should clear out previous values in textbox as they are bound to new school now.

Comment: <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedSchool.SchoolName, Mode = "TwoWay", UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

Comment: @CharismaRise Try this: `var school = new School(); Schools.Add(school); SelectedSchool = school;` That will give you a blank school to work with when you click the button.

Comment: @Muds I agree, I expected the same behaviour but strangely enough, the data does not update with the new object that has no data initialized.

Comment: make it a two way bind like this 

<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedSchool.SchoolName, Mode = "TwoWay", UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

Comment: @Muds It's not a two-way binding issue. Your code doesn't add a new school object to the collection: that's the problem. CharismaRise, try the code edit.

Comment: oh well yea just a small reference glitch may be .. :P

Comment: @Muds my binding looks exactly like yours but still no luck

Comment: @CharismaRise It's not the binding, it's the code in the `AddSchool` method that's the issue. Please try my suggested edit from an earlier comment.

Comment: @Steven Rands Tried this: Schools.Add(SelectedSchool);

            var school = new School();
            Schools.Add(school);
            SelectedSchool = school; But the result is that I still do not get empty item selected and when I select it myself from the list, I get two duplicated entries from the last input

Comment: @CharismaRise My suggested edit was a complete replacement for the `AddSchool` method. Try removing the `Schools.Add(SelectedSchool)` bit from Muds's original code.

Comment: @Steven Rands the three lines add an empty item to the list, while the input is not saved. TextBoxes do not clear either when I press Add

Comment: @CharismaRise The "Add" button as per this code will add a new, blank school to the list which you can then edit the details of using the text boxes. It will not use what is currently in the text boxes to create a new entry in the list. If that's not how you want the UI to behave then we'll need to think of a new approach.

Comment: @Steven Rands very close, except I need to manually navigate to the newly added empty School inside the ComboBox. What I want though is that the empty item automatically gets selected each time I press Add. Thank you

Comment: @CharismaRise Muds is right, setting the `SelectedSchool` property from code should update the text displayed in your text boxes, as long as all of the bindings are correct. Are you sure that the school name (for example) has a binding like this: `{Binding SelectedSchool.Name ...`? Note this will be `Name` (the property on the `School` object) not `SchoolName`. In fact, you shouldn't need the separate `SchoolName`, `SchoolAddress` etc properties anymore as you're no longer binding to them.

Comment: @CharismaRise Ignore that, seems like it's working now. Nice one Muds! Sorry for hijacking the comments.

Comment: no wrries mate :) ... !

@CharismaRise mark it as ans if it worked :)

Comment: @Muds your way seems most logical and clean and makes perfect sense to me. However, when I first click Add, my new School gets added to the list and stays selected, no new empty item gets into the list. If I press Add again, then I get this new empty item on the list. I forgot to mention that I use MahApps Metro package, I hope there is no bug in their Controls.

Comment: when you click add again .. you are deliberately adding a new item into the list... as there is no check on add method before you add SelectedSchool into the list....

Comment: @CharismaRise _"However, when I first click Add, my new School gets added to the list and stays selected"_ - Do you need a `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` on your `ComboBox`?

Comment: @Muds It works indeed with simple WPF but not on the MahApps controls... Thank you very much for your help guys, I will have to look further into why this is happening!

Comment: Glad.... any way whats this MahApps controls.. never worked on tese .. are these popular ?

Comment: The root of the problem was that my ViewModelBase class did not implement INotifyPropertyChanged. So now everything is perfect. MahApps are Metroc styled WPF controls: http://mahapps.com, some cool stuff.

Answer (score 1):

**The answer from @Muds is probably the best way of doing what you want. I'm leaving my answer here just to illustrate an alternative approach.**

---

First of all you should change the type of your `SelectedSchool` property to `School`, not object. Then, in its property setter, set the `SchoolName`, `SchoolAddress` and `SchooTelephone` (typo?) properties based on the selection:

```
SchoolName = _SelectedSchool.Name;
// etc...
```

This will mean that when you change the selection in the combo box the selected school's details will be transferred to the text boxes.

In your `AddSchool` method, after you have added the new school to the list, just clear out the properties that are bound to the text boxes:

```
SchoolName = String.Empty;
// etc...
```

Your idea of using the same button to both add and edit school details won't be feasible without a little additional work. You need a unique identifier for each school: that way, when you click the "Add or Edit" button you can look in the list of schools to see if that particular school already exists. If it does, then it's an edit, otherwise it's a new school.

Your problem is that you have no unique identifier. You can't use the school name as this could change during an edit. Try adding another property to your `School` object to use as an identifier, something like an `int` would do (you don't have to show this value to the user). Then, when you create a new school, create a new unique "school ID" number and assign it to that school.